# Spring boot swagger or open api integration error in new version 2.6.0+

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, microservices, openapi

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

while using swagger for my application which is having version issue while running the application.

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springdoc/core/conditions/MultipleOpenApiSupportCondition has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes

we tried changing java version java 8 to java 11 but not working due to class file version issues.

tried lowering the spring boot version then also it wont work.

Comment: reference link for more explanation  https://springdoc.org/v1/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting swagger issue using spring fox then read below.
Kindly note the compiler version issue as below:

```
49 = Java 5
50 = Java 6
51 = Java 7
52 = Java 8
53 = Java 9
54 = Java 10
55 = Java 11
56 = Java 12
57 = Java 13
58 = Java 14
59 = Java 15
60 = Java 16
61 = Java 17
62 = Java 18
63 = Java 19
64 = Java 20
```

if you are using java version 8/11 then below dependency you can use.
Note: springdoc-openapi v1.7.0 is the latest Open Source release supporting Spring Boot 2.x and 1.x.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

use the above dependency and access the api using below sample url.
http://localhost:8765/swagger-ui.html

for Spring-boot v3 (Java 17 & Jakarta EE 9)

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
   </dependency>
```